# Wakelock and webview interval

Tags: android, webview, intervals, wakelock

I have a Activity contain a webview. Webview load a snippet of javascript that call a servcie api with a interval after 1 minutes. After I press power button, screen device is off and about 5 minutes, Javacsript interval in webview stop. I try to use Partial Wake Locks but it seem not work. 
In manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

In onCreate function:

```
 PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK |
            PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
            PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "sleeplock");
    mWakeLock.acquire();
```

Have any idea about this? What did i do wrong?

Comment: My target device is Samsung S7.

Comment: I found requestIgnoreBatteryOptimization. But after request success, app is not in white list, don't understand why